# Transparent section of png causes unsightly / different refraction in glass

Tags: modeling, rendering

If you look at where the label's edges are notated in red, and then look at those same edge areas in the other bottles you'll see an unsightly / different refraction when rendered. Why causes this? How can I get rid of it?
[image]

Comment: If you want this answered you need to provide relevant information. Show us the shader and the image you used.

Comment: Re-uploaded new image with requested info.

Comment: It looks like these are the borders of the .png image which provides label on the bottle. This changing is even visible on the bottle on the right, which is rendered on grey background.

Comment: No, it's not just the borders... yes you can see borders but if you look you'll see the entire transparent area of the png is refracting differently. If it were just a line, border or edge I'd just fix it in Photoshop and be on my way. :)  But because it's refracting differently, that's not something I can 'fix' in Photoshop.

Comment: PNG are not a very good choice for alpha. Try tga or tiff that stores a physical copy of the alpha channel. Also have you tried separating the bottle and the label into 2 physical model instead of combining them in one material?

Comment: Ahhh.. ok. Good information on tga / tiff. Thanks. And I don't yet know how to "separate the bottle and the label into 2 physical models".